# Why I get "execution failed for task ' process debug google services" error when I add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.4.0.

Comment: post gradle file here.

Comment: plz share gradle file....!!!